# Make video from frames captured in captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection

Tags: ios, avcapture

How to make movie from frames captured in
-captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection
and save to photo library ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I haven't noticed. See edited answer maybe you find it useful.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef) CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
        [_coreImageContext drawImage:image inRect:[image extent] fromRect:[image extent]];
        [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER ];
    }
```